# Does $\sum 3^{-\sqrt{n}}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to find out whether this series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{3^{\sqrt{n}}}$$

The $n$th term, ratio, and root tests are inconclusive, Abel's test doesn't apply (or I can't think of how to separate out part of the sequence), and I can't figure out a series to compare this to that'll work.

WolframAlpha says it converges by the comparison test, BTW.  It just doesn't tell me what it compared the series *to*.

Comment: A good choice might be $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: How did you come up with that?

Comment: It's one of the "simplest converging series," besides the geometric ones. Clearly, yours is not geometric, so among those who remain $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$ would be a natural candidate.

Comment: @user234494 My logic was that $\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}$ should decay very fast since it's a bit like a geometric series. As such, it should decay faster than $\frac{1}{n^2}$ since $\frac{1}{n^2}$ doesn't decay all that fast.

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  I'll just have to prove that $n^2 \lt 3^{\sqrt{n}}$ for some large enough $n$, now.  Thanks.

Comment: As a way to prove (the other) inequality, you could write $n^2 = e^{2\ln n}$ and $3^{\sqrt{n}} = e^{\sqrt{n}\ln 3}$; and compare asymptotically the exponents.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to prove that $\dfrac{1}{3^{\sqrt n}} < \dfrac{1}{n^2}$ for large enough $n$ -- that is $n^2 < 3^{\sqrt{n}}$?

Comment: Yep.  Typed it wrong.

Comment: A tactic potentially simpler than the existing answers is differentiation. You can show that $f < 0$ after a certain value by fining a value where that's true, and showing its derivative is also less than zero after that point. This is an iterative process, so to prove the second half, you prove the result for $f'$, which you do by proving the result for $f''$, etc. In this case if you use $f = n^2 - 3^{\sqrt{n}}$ it should halt after a few steps, requiring you only to show that $3^{\sqrt{n}}$ is eventually greater than some constant. (or zero after another step)

Answer (score 9):

Here's something different, that doesn't require comparing $n^2$ with $3^{\sqrt{n}}$, or any similar comparison:

$$\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}\leq\frac{1}{3^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}$$

And the sequence $\{\left\lfloor\sqrt{1}\right\rfloor,\left\lfloor\sqrt{2}\right\rfloor,\left\lfloor\sqrt{3}\right\rfloor,\ldots\}$ is equal to $$\{\overbrace{1,1,1}^3,\overbrace{2,\ldots,2}^{5},\overbrace{3,\ldots,3}^{7},\ldots,\overbrace{k,\ldots,k}^{2k+1},\ldots\}\text{.}$$ This follows from understanding that consecutive perfect squares differ by increasing odd numbers. Or equivalently that the sum of consecutive odd integers $3+5+7+\cdots$ is always $1$ shy of a perfect square.

So
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}&<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k+1}{3^{k}}\\
&=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{3^{k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{k}}\\
&=2\cdot\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\\
&=2
\end{align}$$

Not only is the sum convergent, it's less than $2$. You can get a better upper bound by leaving the initial terms alone instead of using the floor function. For instance, this same approach can be used with $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{1}}}+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{3}}}+\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor}}
&=\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{1}}}+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{3}}}+1\\
&\approx1.69\ldots
\end{align}$$
which is a better upper bound. (A CAS says the true value is approximately $1.34\ldots$)

---

For an even better approximation that you can't immediately tell is over or under, replace each term in $\sum_{n=N^2}^{(N+1)^2-1}\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}$ (the portion of the series corresponding to one of the constant substrings in $\{\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor\}$) with the average of the end terms: $\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{N^2}}}$ and $\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{(N+1)^2}}}$. So

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}
&\approx\sum_{N=1}^{\infty}\frac12\left(\frac{1}{3^N}+\frac{1}{3^{N+1}}\right)(2N+1)\\
&=\frac43
\end{align}$$
I'm not offering error analysis, but you can note that this does indeed get within $0.6\%$ of the exact value.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\log_e n \leq \sqrt{n}$ for $n\geq 1$. Then
$$3^{\log_e n} = n^{\log_e3}\leq 3^{\sqrt{n}}$$
This will imply, for n large enough
$$\frac{1}{n^{\log_e3}}\geq \frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}$$
Now $\log_e3 > 1$.

Comment: Yes. $a^{\log b} = b^{\log a}$ for $a$ and $b$ positive.

Comment: Yes. I had initially thought that you didn't explicitly write this in your answer, but in fact it is there.

Comment: I suppose it might be "common knowledge" that $\sqrt{n}$ eventually exceeds $\log n$. But this is mathematically just as challenging to prove as the fact that $3^{\sqrt{n}}$ eventually exceeds $n^2$, the answer from the comment thread.

Answer (score 2):

One way to show that this series converges can be to compare it to $\int_0^\infty (1/3)^\sqrt x dx$, which is convergent.

Edit - You can solve this integral by substituting $t=\sqrt x$, and then integrating the resulting integral by parts.

Comment: And how would convince someone that this integral is convergent?

Comment: @alex.jordan: In general, for $n>0$ we have $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{^{\LARGE-\sqrt[n]x}}~dx~=~n!~$

Comment: @alex.jordan, I would use substitution - $\sqrt x = t$. You can then solve the integral using integration by parts.

Comment: @RoiBlumberg Oh good, then +1. Is it worth clarifying that in the answer? Maybe not if you are leaving something for OP to do.

Comment: No, you're right, I will clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

If we stick to general tests, we
can apply the condensation test ($a_n=\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}$ is decreasing) + the $n$-th root (for example) test.
$$
\sum_n a_n \le \sum_n (2n+1)a_{n^2}=\sum_n \frac{2n+1}{3^n}\\
\lim_{n} \left(\frac{2n+1}{3^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{3}<1
$$

(The condensation is done through the $\varphi(n)=n^2$ subsequence, in this way we "eliminate" the square root.)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Here, $f(x)=3^{-\sqrt{x}}$, then your series converges if and only if $\int_1^{\infty}3^{-\sqrt{x}}dx$ converges.

But $\int_1^{\infty}3^{-\sqrt{x}}dx\overset{x=u^2}=\int_1^{\infty}2ue^{-(\ln3)u}du=-\frac{2u}{\ln3}e^{-(\ln3)u}\vert_1^{\infty}+\frac{2}{\ln3}\int_1^{\infty}e^{-(\ln3)u}du=\frac{2}{\ln3}+\frac{2}{(\ln3)^2}$, it converges so does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^{-\sqrt{n}}$.