# Cauchy's $n$-th root test: $\lambda_n$-th root test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\lambda_n=n$ and $A=\overline{\lim}_n |a_n|^{\frac{1}{\lambda_n}}$.
Cauchy's ($n$-th) root test states that

- $A<1 \ \implies \ \sum_n |a_n|< \infty$
- $A>1 \ \implies \ \sum_n |a_n|= \infty$

If we assume only that:
$$\frac{\lambda_n}{\log(n)}\to \infty$$
then we can prove similar claims:

- If $A<1$ then by the properties of $\lambda_n$ and $\overline{\lim}$ there is a $n_0$ such that if $n\ge n_0$:
  $$
      |a_n|^{\frac{1}{\lambda_n}}\le \sup_{k\ge n} |a_k|^{\frac{1}{\lambda_k}}< \frac{1+A}{2}=q<1 \\
  $$
  $$
    \log(q)\frac{\lambda_n}{\log(n)}<-2 \\
  $$
  $$
  \implies |a_n| < q^{\lambda_n} = 
  e^{\log(q)\lambda_n} = e^{\log(n) \log(q)\frac{\lambda_n}{\log(n)}} = n^{\log(q)\frac{\lambda_n}{\log(n)}}< \frac{1}{n^2}
  $$
- If $A>1$ then there is a subsequence $a_{k(n)}$ for which $|a_{k(n)}|>1$, therefore $a_n$ is not a null sequence.

Use cases:

- [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1252181/does-sum-3-sqrtn-converge-or-diverge)
  $$
  \sum_n \frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}<\infty\ \hspace{2cm}
  \lambda_n=\sqrt{n}\\
  $$
- [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459163/convergence-of-sum-n-0-infty-fracne-sqrt-n)
  $$
  \sum_n \frac{n}{e^{\sqrt{n}}}<\infty\ \hspace{2cm}
  \lambda_n=\sqrt{n}\\
  $$
- [1]+[2]
  $$
  r>1,\ \alpha, \beta>0\ \ \ \implies \sum_n \frac{n^\beta}{r^{n^\alpha}}<\infty\ \hspace{2cm} \lambda_n=n^{\alpha}\\
  $$

Questions:

- Is the derivation correct?
- I think that it is a toy test, but for *some* sequences it provides a routine way to study the convergence.
  What do you think about it?

Comment: At beginning you set $\lambda_n=n,$ in the following you use different forms of $\lambda_n$ and you talk about "properties of $\lambda_n$", but you never give such properties

Comment: In the classical Cauchy test $\lambda_n=n$. This toy test is about $\lambda_n$'s  for which $\frac{\lambda_n}{\log(n)}\to \infty$, which is slightly general than the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation of the test is correct. I am not sure how useful the test is in practice, since off the top of my head I can't see examples where this test works and its application is straightforward but an application of the comparison test (or, in case of eventually monotonic sequences like your examples, the integral comparison test or the condensation test) would be considerably more difficult.

Your test is in these examples simpler, but whether the gain in simplicity is large enough to outweigh the burden of remembering yet another test I cannot yet tell.

But even if it turns out to be not very useful in practice, it was good thinking to come up with it.

Comment: thanks for your time! I see that it is not a very strong test, but anyway it slightly generalizes the original one...

Comment: I would say it generalises the ordinary root test more than just slightly. And it's quite a bit stronger than the ordinary root test, which itself is stronger than the ratio test, so it is a fairly strong test. The problem it has is that it's not usually obvious which $\lambda_n$ sequence to take, and when it is obvious, the even stronger comparison test (which is an if and only if criterion after all) is also easy to apply.

Comment: I told "slightly", because it cannot decide on $p$-sequences: ${n^p}^{\frac{1}{\lambda_n}}=e^{p\frac{\log(n)}{\lambda_n}}\to 1$, for any $\lambda_n$. It was the point why i started to hack the original one. :-(

Comment: I see. Yes, those decrease too slowly for this test. But if you have a monotonic (eventually monotonic suffices) sequence, the condensation test or the integral comparison test are very powerful and usually at least one is easy to apply.